# Use Kotlin field from Java project problem

Tags: java, android, kotlin, koin

I would like to use Koin library from Java. According to this tutorial, Koin modules can be written in Kotlin even using Java in the rest of a project.

https://insert-koin.io/docs/quickstart/android-java/

I use also @JvmField annotation for the module field because in the source code of this tutorial it is used

https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/quickstart/getting-started-koin-android/app/src/main/kotlin/org/koin/sample/AppModule.kt

In my project I use `koinInjector` which is a list of modules

```
import org.koin.android.java.KoinAndroidApplication;
import org.koin.core.KoinApplication;

import static org.koin.core.context.DefaultContextExtKt.startKoin;
import static com.x.y.KoinInjectorKt.koinInjector;

public class App extends Singleton {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        KoinApplication koin = KoinAndroidApplication
                .create(this)
                .modules(koinInjector);
        startKoin(koin);
    }
}
```

KoinInjector.kt:

```
@JvmField
val koinInjector: List<Module> = listOf(
        localDbModule,
)
```

But during build I get the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import static com.x.y.KoinInjectorKt.koinInjector;
                               ^
  symbol:   class KoinInjectorKt
  location: package com.x.y
```

Comment: What is the file name of kotlin file where `koinInjector` is declared?

Comment: `KoinInjector` . Whereas the name `KoinInjectorKt` in import was generated automatically

Comment: Perhaps a (subtle) difference in build scripts? Could you include your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"`

to build.gradle and

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` to build.gradle (app)`

Now it works.

Thanks @Jeroen Steenbeeke for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the code with -

```
import org.koin.android.java.KoinAndroidApplication; 
import org.koin.core.KoinApplication;

import static org.koin.core.context.DefaultContextExtKt.startKoin;
import static com.x.y.KoinInjectorKt.koinInjector;

public class App extends Singleton {
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    KoinApplication koin = KoinAndroidApplication
            .create(this)
            .modules(listOf(localDbModule));
    startKoin(koin);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

remove this import

'import static com.x.y.KoinInjectorKt.koinInjector;'

and write your code like this

```
public class App extends Singleton {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    List<Module> list = new ArrayList<Module>();
    list.add(localDbModule);
    KoinApplication koin = KoinAndroidApplication
            .create(this)
            .modules(list);
    startKoin(koin);
 }
}
```